# Split Mongo Collection (by Index)

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, django-celery, nosql

I currently have a long-running operation (running in Python+Celery) that goes through an entire Mongo collection of about 43,000,000 elements and does an analysis on the elements without making any changes to those elements.

As this collection has grown the operation has started to take longer (obviously) and now is periodically failing usually due to a timeout to a different database.

I would like to split this operation into several smaller operations--perhaps operating on just a few million elements--and I'm wondering about the best way to produce the queries that will do the splitting. I only have one index on this collection and its the `_id`.

The obvious answer seemed to be something like:

```
# This is executed in parallel on different servers
def doAnalysis(skipped,limit) 
    db.<collection>.find().skip(skipped).limit(limit)

...

# This is the parent task
elemsToAnalyze = db.<collection>.find().count()/10;
for i in range(0,10:
    doAnalysis(elemsToAnalyze * i, elemsToAnalyze)
```

But it turns out the `.skip()` takes a **long** time--basically just as long as actually performing the analysis! Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`skip()` can be very slow in this kind of case. You could do range queries instead by using the last `_id` of the batch to query the next batch. Something like this:

```
db.<collection>.find({ "_id" : { $gte: prev_batch_last_id } } ).sort( { _id : 1 } ).limit(limit);
```

You'll have to store the last id of the batch to a variable yourself.

Comment: thanks for your response. The trouble with this method is that I need to know the last_id from the *previously executed* batch. Preferably, I would like to be able to run these processes independently such that they wouldn't need to share data--the benefit would be that they would be parallelizable.

Comment: Is this collection sharded? If so, you could use the chunk bounds as a way to partition the collection.  If not, there are other ways to partition the range of _id's in your collection.

Comment: @ChrisW Based on your sample conde, I thought parallel processing wasn't needed. Do you have multiple databases? If you do, as matulef mentioned, you could use sharding boundaries (if its sharded). If the task that you do for each element is very short, doing the queries in parallel for one db may not speed up the processing at all since the db can only process one query at a time. You can first try (manually) if parallel way is actually quicker or not.